# Perl looping through the Oracle query doesn't produce any data after the first one

Tags: database, oracle, perl

In the code below, I have `@some_array` which is an array of arrays which contains text like name. So

```
@some_array= ([sam, jon, july],[Mike, Han,Tommy],[angie, sita, lanny]);
```

Now when I query the list like `sam jon july` first and `mike han tommy`. Only the execute return the result from the first list others is undef. I don't know why any help will be appreciated.

If I switch the second to first place and run it it will show the first one only. So the problem is it is returning for the first set but for subsequent sets its returning undef. I did enable strict and warnings but it it didn't show any error.

```
my $pointer;
my $db = $db->prepare_cached("
    begin
            :pointer := myFun(:A1);
    end;
            ") or die "Couldn't prepare stat: " . $db->errstr;
$db->bind_param_inout(":pointer", \$pointer, 0, { ora_type => ORA_RSET });

for (my $i = 0; $i < @some_array; $i++) {
    my @firstarray = @{$some_array[$i]};
    my $sql = lc(join(" ", @firstarray));
    print "<pre>$sql</pre>\n";
    $db->bind_param(":A1", $sql);
    $db->execute();
    print "<pre>".Dumper($db->execute())."</pre>\n";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this can work at all, as `execute` returns the “number of rows affected” and not the result of the prepared statement. You also appear to have overwritten your database handle with the return from `prepare_cached`, which will destroy the handle and close the connection.

You should be looking at the `$pointer` variable that you have bound to the SQL variable `:pointer` that receives the result of the stored procedure call.

Comment: Yes I am looking at the pointer only. The thing is I was checking if execute affects any row. And it returns undef after the first pass. The query is right and I am passing the second argument but I am just curious why second pass returns the undef.

Comment: Well your code doesn't show anything that displays `$pointer`, and for some reason you are calling `execute` twice. Is `$sql` displaying correctly?

Comment: I solved the issue, the problem was I was closing the db connection for second loop. I fixed it thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome. But the code you show doesn't do that?